# How to register IEnumerable<IService> In DryIoc Mvc Controller like Autofac Enumeration (IEnumerable<B>, IList<B>, ICollection<B>)

Tags: dryioc

Test Code With Autofac is Ok,but with DryIoc is error. How to make this work.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            private readonly ITestAppService _testAppService;
            private readonly IEnumerable<ITestAppService> _testAppServiceList;
            public HomeController(ITestAppService testAppService, IEnumerable<ITestAppService> testAppServiceList)
            {
                _testAppService = testAppService;
                _testAppServiceList = testAppServiceList;
            }
    }
public class Test1AppService : ITestAppService{}
public class Test2AppService : ITestAppService{}
public interface ITestAppService: IAppService{}
```

The error 'Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor ' is caused by field ITestAppService in controller not the field IEnumerable.Following is my register code.

```
var impls =
                typeof(IAppService).Assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(type =>
                type.IsPublic && 
                !type.IsAbstract && 
                type.GetInterfaces().Length != 0 && typeof(IAppService).IsAssignableFrom(type));

            foreach (var type in impls)
            {
                container.Register(type.GetInterfaces().First(), type, Reuse.Transient);

            }
```

Resolved by dadhi's suggestion,My container is

```
DryIoc.IContainer container = new DryIoc.Container(
                rules =>
                {
                    return rules.WithFactorySelector(Rules.SelectLastRegisteredFactory())
                    .WithResolveIEnumerableAsLazyEnumerable();
                }
            );
```

The dryioc wiki about *Resolving from multiple default services* may need some update. *Rules.SelectLastRegisteredFactory* is a method.

Comment: How do you register IAppTestService, what should go to single dependency, and what to collection?

Comment: The problem is ITestAppService  registration with two implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that consdering two implementations of `ITestAppService` container [doesn't know which to select for the first dependency](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/RulesAndDefaultConventions#markdown-header-resolving-from-multiple-default-services).  But you may explicitly define the convention:

```
var container = new Container(rules => rules
    .WithFactorySelector(Rules.SelectLastRegisteredFactory));
```

Comment: Thanks very much,that works excellently.My Code is like this`DryIoc.IContainer container = new DryIoc.Container(
                rules =>
                {
                    return rules.WithFactorySelector(Rules.SelectLastRegisteredFactory())
                    .WithResolveIEnumerableAsLazyEnumerable();
                }
            );`